# When was the last time a conference final contained 0 champions?

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba

According to [SportsCenter](https://mobile.twitter.com/SportsCenter/status/1411061096102907906), there are 0 champions remaining in the 2021 NBA Playoffs.

[image: 0 champions]

The Suns have reached the NBA finals, but the Bucks and Hawks are still competing for the Eastern Conference Finals.

When was the last time a conference final contained 0 champions?

Comment: I'm not sure how best to research this, but if someone else wants a start, the last time there were 0 champions in an NBA final was 1977.  So if it has happened before, the conference championship stat would have to be between 1971 (when the conference championship format was created) and 1977